# Assigning numerical values to symbolic matrice in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, symbolic-math

I have a 5X6 matrices. The columns of this matrix is q values and rows are pnt values.

B is a matrice that defined using symbolic `q (q1 q2 q3 q4 q5)` values.

```
 for j=1:6                                                                                
      for i=1:5                                                                                                                                     
          B=subs(B,sprintf('q%d',i),pnt(i,j));   
          x=FcnCheck(B,i) 
          A=B(1,4);
          C=B(2,4);
      end
  end
```

when I apply this code, for i=2, q1 value become symbolic again.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you *want* `q1` to remain a symbolic variable in your `B` array in each loop? If so, you appear to be overwriting the `B` array, which is getting rid of `q1` and permanently replacing it with a number.

Comment: I want to get rid of q1 and write its numeric value instead